# Structure member's values not printing correctly except the first

Tags: c, struct

**My program:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

struct student
{
    int id;
    char name[30];
    float percentage;
};

int main()
{
struct student s={1, 'heeena', 30};

printf("ID is %d\n name is %s\n percentage  is %f",s.id,s.name,s.percentage);

return(0);

}
```

The output of the above program is:

```
 ID is 1
 name is a...
 percentage  is 0.000000
```

In place of  `...`,  there is non ASCII character which I can't draw here. How do I correct the program so that it shows expected values of the structure as shown below?

```
 ID is 1
 name is heeena
 percentage  is 30
```

I am compiling this under Ubuntu  12.04 using gcc

Comment: Yet another `'` versus `"` question; there's been a few of those recently. To be fair, I'm not actually 100% sure what's going on with the float though.

Comment: Try putting double quotes around `"henna"`.  Single quotes indicate a single character, double quotes indicates a null-terminated string of characters, which is what you want.

Comment: also, it should be `int main(void)` and don't put parentheses around return value

Comment: Pay attention to your compiler warnings.  If your compiler is not giving you warnings, find out how to enable them, or get a better compiler.  Since you say you're using GCC on Ubuntu, use at least `-Wall`.  Personally, I compile with `-Wall -Wextra -Werror -Wstrict-prototypes -Wmissing-prototypes -Wold-style-definitions`.  And don't forget to end your output with a newline.

Comment: @DennisMeng I was going to speculate about `int` vs `const char *` screwing up where `printf` is looking for the third argument, but `s.name` should have the type `printf` expects for `%s` (it's just being *initialized* to garbage) so that won't fly.

Answer (score 3):

The warning here is

```
character constant too long
```

In C and C++ character codes are written using single quotes, e.g. 'a' gives the ASCII code for the letter 'a' (67), and '\n' gives the ASCII code for newline (10). This error occurs if single quotes are used to enclose more than one character.

Thus replace the following line

```
struct student s={1, 'heeena', 30};
```

with

```
struct student s={1, "heeena", 30};
```

Comment: then why single quote in '\n', there are two characters.\ and n..right ?

Comment: Yeah! but try out for '/n' which is invalid.I think it is ASCII convention built in C compiler. '\n' can be drilled down to ASCII Code for newline

Comment: No, `\n` is a single newline character.

Answer (score 1):

May be typo.. You will have to put `""` on your `char[]`

```
struct student s={1, "heeena", 30};
```

Answer (score 1):

I thing

strcpy(s.name,"heeena");

is the best way to define s.name.

Answer (score 1):

you are using an array of characters and that is a string. For giving an input of an individual character you can input in this form(using single quotes)

```
char c = 'x';
```

so that gives the c character variable a value x;

and for array of characters(i.e. string) you need to use double quotes

```
char s[30]="heena";
```

so in the above program you change the format of your input. Change single quotes over heena to double quotes.

Answer (score 0):

its just assignment miss match
it expects string

you have given 
'heeena'
charge to 
"heeena"

then percentage automatically gives correct answer